# Is there anything like Code Igniter's DBForge for C#?

Tags: c#, .net, php, codeigniter

> The [Database Forge Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/forge.html) contains functions that help you manage your database.

It can:

- Create or drop a database
- Add fields and keys
- Create, drop and modify a table

I was wondering if anything like that existed for C# or .Net.

Otherwise, I think I have a little project on my hands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the perfect thing. The only minor drawback is that it is limited to Microsoft SQL Server.

The thing is called [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) and here are two good tutorials:

- [How to create tables](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/01/27/2775.aspx)
- [How to create stored procedures](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/01/27/2774.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft ADO Ext. implements that functionality... see [Create Database Using C#](http://waleedelkot.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-create-database-using-c.html), but it is a COM component may be managed one will be valuable

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can help the library to work with DataBases from CodeProject: [Database Utilities for C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csharp_db_utilities.aspx)

Comment: Considering there hasn't been any update since January 2008, I'm gonna pass on it.