# How to create database from codebehind in ASP.net 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I need to create database from codebehind in ASP.net 2.0.

Please help.

Comment: Please name the database product.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535623/is-there-anything-like-code-igniters-dbforge-for-c

Answer (score 1):

May be like this:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE database_name", connection);
command.Connection.Open();
command.ExecuteReader();
connection.Close();
```